# Code::Blocks, c++, magick++ any demo results in: mingw32-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files

Tags: c++, image, g++, codeblocks, magick++

I am trying to use Magick++ with Code::Blocks (both are latest versions).
I use win7 x64 and I installed both ImageMagick x86 and x64 dynamic (with DLLs).

Every time I try to run a demo c++ file (like the code below,) I get the same message:

```
\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\include\"  -c C:\Users\ad\Desktop\C++\Magick++\test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

does anybody has experienced this?
Could you help me to make it work?

I put a `.jpg` file "wall.jpg" in the same folder as the project.

Thanks

Source code from the magick++ `demo` folder

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  InitializeMagick(*argv);

  // Construct the image object. Seperating image construction from the
  // the read operation ensures that a failure to read the image file
  // doesn't render the image object useless.
  Image image;
  try {
    // Read a file into image object
    image.read( "wall.jpg" );

    // Crop the image to specified size (width, height, xOffset, yOffset)
    image.crop( Geometry(100,100, 100, 100) );

    // Write the image to a file
    image.write( "x.gif" );
  }
  catch( Exception &error_ )
    {
      cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
      return 1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your input path is error set or your account don't have privilege to read the file in "C:\Users\ad\Desktop\C++\Magick++\test\main.cpp",check it and try again

Answer (score 1):

Hello ,

the problem is not the missing "wall.jpg",
but the compilation process (creating the executable binary) , as your example output shows :

```
mingw32-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
```

To find out what is going wrong, you should post the command you run 
and the complete error output.

Best,

Jack

Comment: Hi, sorry to be such a beginner, but I don't understand. I just have a c++ file (test.cpp) containing the code above, and I try to build it. The error message appears when I do that.

Comment: The error message seems incomplete;
How do you exactly try to build it?

Comment: maybe u should check the 1st message on the top of the page, here the error msg is complete

Comment: Dear Adrien,

I would like to see the >full< "Build log"; in the CodeBlocks IDE you can see these tabs "Build log", "Build Messages", etc.

Comment: I tried to compile examples (by hand) using cygwin instead and it worked. What about trying out cygwin? If you are willing to try it out, I will post a Makefile

Comment: That's really nice of you, if you can shortly explain how to use cygwin with the Makefile...

Answer (score 0):

I think the error happened in the first sentence of main:InitializeMagick(*argv), you can debug into this calling, may be it's caused by the NULL pointer of argv.

**Oh, no, the project didn't even compile! (see the error msg)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should revise the way you used to create your project. **Personally**, i double checked how to create a project and luckily worked.